# How to make a large distance between widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Tell me how to correctly make a large indent between `RedeemButton()` and button ? I need to make such an indent as shown in the screenshot.

**body**

```
Column(childre: [
            const RedeemButton(
                textStyle: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite,
                buttonStyle: constants.Styles.smallMediumTextStyleWhite),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              child: Text(
                'Hello',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: could you please describe what you expect on the picture?

Comment: Nothing, I just need to have an indent from the content and buttons at the bottom.

Comment: You need to make such an indent as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a Column Widget, to separate your 2 children you can use the `mainAxisAlignment` set to `spaceBetween`, like this:

```
    Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [...
```

If you want a spacific distance number, you can set a `SizedBox` Widget between them, and set a height that fits your need in a `height` property

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Spacer** widget if you want.